# Unable to connect application-server listening port on VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have deployed an application server on Linux VM instance. Application is running successfully and listening on port 3465. I opened the port 3465 by adding firewall rule, But still not able to connect application from my local windows machine on listening port.

I used following IP-port to connect with VM instance application from my local machine,

**IP address:** VM instance's external IP

**Port:** 3465

1) I have added firewall rule to open port

```
elon_musk@archway-146712:~$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME             NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW     DENY
<firewall-rule>  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:3465
```

2) I tried adding forwarding rule, but not worked

```
elon_musk@archway-146712:~$ gcloud compute target-instances list
NAME       ZONE           INSTANCE         NAT_POLICY
<ti-name>  asia-south1-a  <instance-name>  NO_NAT

elon_musk@archway-146712:~$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
NAME       REGION       IP_ADDRESS      IP_PROTOCOL  TARGET
<fr-name>  asia-south1  xx.xxx.148.135  TCP          asia-south1-a/targetInstances/<ti-name>
```

> Note: when I created forwarding rule, system automatically used IP address other than VM instance's external IP. so again question is whether I should use IP address of forwarding rule or VM instance's external IP?

Here is the Linux VM instance iptables configuration

```
elon_musk@archway-146712:~$ sudo iptables -t filter -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2609 packets, 376K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2433 packets, 237K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Are you running your application on a Windows or a Linux instance?
Are you able to ping the external IP of your server from your local machine?
Witch are the Targets and Source filters  of your firewall rule? By the way a forwarding rule should be not useful in this setup

Comment: I'm running application in Linux instance, yes I'm able to ping external IP from my local windows machine

Comment: And I guess your application can be reached without any problem on the local host. Does it work as well a telnet with the very same IP and port? By the way it seems 99% a firewall problem, did you modify iptables on the server?

Comment: @GalloCedrone, I haven't modified iptables. Please verify iptables details that I added in post.

Comment: I cannot spot any evident mistake in the iptables configuration so if the firewall rule applies to your vm and it has a source range including your local machine the firewall in this case seems not to be the problem, but just a telnet test can tell us. Are you running you application inside a Docker container? If yes, how did you bind the ports? Your application uses the 3465 port only?